# Debugging a 500 Internal Server Error in an Express.js Stripe Payment Implementation

Tags: reactjs, express, stripe-payments

Im trying to integrate stripe into the current project that I'm working on.  I made a component that would take in the user's credit card number, the expiry date, the cvv/cvc numbers along with the person name. When the user enters their info and they submit the form a POST request is supposed to be sent to my paymentInfoDB.json file (placeholder database) to store their info. This way the user can store multiple payment methods and either delete them or set one of them as their default payment method. Right now Im experiencing an internal server error saying it cannot GET the endpoint Im trying to hit. THE ERROR: [image: my error message in the console]. I think the problem is with my server.js file or my component its itself honestly I don't know and I've lost almost all hope. Someone, anyone please help me. Or show me an alternative way that I can achieve what Im trying to to, save the user's payment info so they can set a default or delete it.

I have a root directory called blackboard that houses my four main directories, backend, node_modules, public, and src. In my backend I have my .env file which has my private stripe test key, and my file called paymentInfoDB.json which is currently an empty array. The backend directory also houses my server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');
const multer = require('multer');
const https = require('https');
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.env') });
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

const app = express();
const port = 5500;

// SSL certificate paths
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../key.pem'), 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../cert.pem'), 'utf8');
const credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate };

// Create HTTPS server
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

// Serve static files from 'public' directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));

// Enable CORS for all routes
app.use(cors());

// Middleware to parse JSON body
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// A line that serves static files from the 'uploads' directory
app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')));

// The file where my address data is currently stored
const PAYMENT_INFO_FILE = path.join(__dirname, './paymentInfoDB.json')

// GET route for all paymentMethods
app.get('/paymentMethods', (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile(PAYMENT_INFO_FILE, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error("Error reading file:", err);
        return res.status(500).send('An error occurred reading the DB.');
      }
  
      // Send back the raw data since it's already a JSON string
      res.status(200).send(data);
    });
});

// POST route for new paymentInfo
app.post('/paymentInfo', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Create a Stripe token
        const token = await stripe.tokens.create({
            card: {
                number: req.body.cardNumber,
                exp_month: req.body.expMonth,
                exp_year: req.body.expYear,
                cvc: req.body.cvc,
            },
        });

        const newEntry = {
            id: uuidv4(),
            holderName: req.body.holderName,
            stripeToken: token.id, // Use the token id from the Stripe response
        };

        // Read the current DB
        const data = await fs.promises.readFile(PAYMENT_INFO_FILE, 'utf8');
        let DB = JSON.parse(data);

        // Add the new entry to the array
        DB.push(newEntry);

        // Write the updated DB back to the file
        await fs.promises.writeFile(PAYMENT_INFO_FILE, JSON.stringify(DB, null, 2), 'utf8');
        res.status(201).json({ message: 'Payment method saved successfully.' });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred processing the payment info.' });
    }
});

// Start the server
httpsServer.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`HTTPS Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

my src directory currently handles my component, my stripe.js, app.js file, and another .env file to handle my publishable test stripe key.
My payment component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useStripe, useElements, CardNumberElement, CardExpiryElement, CardCvcElement } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';

const Payment = () => {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();
  const [paymentLog, setPaymentLog] = useState([]);
  const [cardComplete, setCardComplete] = useState(false);
  const [indexToEdit, setIndexToEdit] = useState(null);
  const [expiryComplete, setExpiryComplete] = useState(false);
  const [cvcComplete, setCvcComplete] = useState(false);
  const [paymentData, setPaymentData] = useState({
    holderName: ''
  });

  const baseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL;

  const inputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setPaymentData({ ...paymentData, [name]: value });
};

  const handleCardChange = (event) => {
    console.log('Card Number Complete:', event.complete);
    setCardComplete(event.complete);
  };
  
  const handleExpiryChange = (event) => {
    console.log('Expiry Complete:', event.complete);
    setExpiryComplete(event.complete);
  };
  
  const handleCvcChange = (event) => {
    console.log('CVC Complete:', event.complete);
    setCvcComplete(event.complete);
  };

  const paymentInfoSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      console.error('Stripe.js has not loaded yet.');
      // Show an error message to your user
      return;
    }

    // Optionally add some UI indication that the process is happening
    // e.g., disabling the submit button, showing a spinner, etc.

    const cardNumberElement = elements.getElement(CardNumberElement);
    const cardExpiryElement = elements.getElement(CardExpiryElement);
    const cardCvcElement = elements.getElement(CardCvcElement);

    console.log('Card Details:', {
      cardComplete,
      expiryComplete,
      cvcComplete,
      holderName: paymentData.holderName,
      // Do not log the actual card number, expiry, or CVC for security reasons
    });

    if (!cardComplete || !expiryComplete || !cvcComplete) {
      console.error('Please complete all card details.');
      // Show an error message to your user
      return;
    }

    // Create a token using the card information
    const result = await stripe.createToken(cardNumberElement, {
      name: paymentData.holderName,
      // You can include additional card information here if needed
    });

    // Re-enable the UI if you've disabled any elements

    if (result.error) {
      console.error('Error:', result.error.message);
      // Show an error message to your user
      return;
    }

    const stripeToken = result.token.id; // Get the token ID

    const paymentInfo = {
        holderName: paymentData.holderName,
        stripeToken: stripeToken // This should only be used on the server-side
    };

    const url = indexToEdit == null ? `${baseUrl}/paymentInfo` : `${baseUrl}/paymentInfo/${paymentLog[indexToEdit].id}`;
    const method = indexToEdit == null ? 'POST' : 'PUT';

    fetch(url, {
      method: method,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(paymentInfo),
    })
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok: ' + response.statusText);
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log('Success:', data);
      // Update your UI here to show the payment method was saved
      // For example, you could clear the form or show a success message
      setPaymentLog((currentLog) => {
        const updatedLog = [...currentLog];
        if (indexToEdit != null) {
          updatedLog[indexToEdit] = data;
        } else {
          updatedLog.push(data);
        }
        return updatedLog;
      });
  
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
      // Show an error message to your user
    });
  };  

  return (
  
      <form onSubmit={paymentInfoSubmit}>
        <input 
          className='holderName' 
          value={paymentData.holderName} 
          name='holderName' 
          type='text' 
          onChange={inputChange} 
          placeholder="Cardholder name"/>
        <CardNumberElement className='cardNumber' onChange={handleCardChange}/>
        <CardExpiryElement onChange={handleExpiryChange}/>
        <CardCvcElement onChange={handleCvcChange}/>
        <button type="submit" disabled={!stripe || !cardComplete || !expiryComplete || !cvcComplete}>Save Payment Method</button>
      </form>
   
  );
};

export default Payment;
```

my stripe.js file:

```
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';

const stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY);

export default stripePromise;
```

my app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Elements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import stripePromise from './stripe'; 
import Payment from './components/payment'; 

function App() {
  return (
    <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
      <Payment />
    </Elements>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Someone please help me resolve this.

Comment: 500 is a server side error - how are you debugging this?  Using some development studio and its debugging tools?

Comment: Please tell me this is just a sample and not for real credit card information being stored in an unencrypted manner in JSON files.

Comment: This is a test im using the 42 repeating number and a made up expiry date and cvv and card holder name

Comment: I do not think you'd want to store PII data on your end unless you're PCI compliant. Are you getting 500 error each time, or is it more intermittent? I recommend that you save the payment method details and then build a UI for your customer to delete or choose other payment methods.

Comment: This is just a test. I later want to move all my backend stuff to a secure database like mongoDB. And the 500 error happens everytime I try and click the save button to send the payment info to my current backend.

Comment: As for debugging I've been trying to simplify the component to just work with card number information and create an even simpler sample of this current sample code along with using ChatGBT.